# Combining CASE and LIMIT in mysql

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table with a similar structure as this one:

field 1 |  field 2 | field 3

> 1 - - - - - 4 - - - - **thisone**
>
> 2 - - - - - 3 - - - - this_will_be_selected
>
> 3 - - - - - 2 - - - - this_will_be_selected
>
> 4 - - - - - 2 - - - - this_will_be_selected
>
> 1 - - - - - 4 - - - - **this_one_could_also_be** instead of the first one
>
> 6 - - - - - 4 - - - - **this_will_be_selected** because there is no other field2=4 AND field1=6

What I'd like to do is obtain **ALL field3 when field2 != 4** and ***limit 1*** in the query whenever field2 = 4

So, for this one query, I would obtain:

field1 = 1
field3 = thisone

field1 = 2
field3 = this_will_be_selected

field1 = 3
field3 = this_will_be_selected

field1 = 4
field3 = this_will_be_selected

field1 = 6
field3 = this_will_be_selected

field1 = 1 and its field 3 "this_one_could_also_be" **won't be selected**

I hope I made myself clear!

My idea was similar to this:

```
SELECT field1, field3 FROM table WHERE LIMIT (CASE field2 WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE ...;
```

The problem is obviously that it will limit the number of rows retrieved **in total** but what I'd like is something like `DISTINCT` with field2 but i'm not understanding how I should do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is what you're after:

```
SELECT field3 FROM MyTable
WHERE field2 != 4
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(field3) FROM MyTable
WHERE field2 = 4
GROUP BY field1;
```

The `MAX()` function makes the arbitrary choice which field3 to display. The `GROUP BY` ensures that only one row is returned per distinct field1 where field2 is 4.

Comment: I see... and if I want to select field1 too?

`SELECT field3,field1 FROM MyTable
WHERE field2 != 4
UNION ALL
SELECT MAX(field3),field1 FROM MyTable
WHERE field2 = 4
GROUP BY field1;` ?

Comment: Yes, you can simply add field1 to the select query, because it is already grouped on. If you would want to also select field2 you would have to add field2 to the grouping clause: `GROUP BY field1, field2`.

Comment: and related to performance issues, won't the query run all the records and only after select the `MAX()` of it? Isn't it possible for the runtime to stop immediately after founding one?

Comment: No, I don't believe such an aggregate function exists, mostly because it's hard to think of a realistic scenario in which that would be useful. If you want to select a `first` value based on some logic, you probably need to generate a rownumber, but that will probably only make the query slower.